# vue-chartjs - Do Experienced Vue Developers use this wrapper?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am refactoring my first pass Vue dashboard application, which uses vue-chartjs to access chart.js.

As part of doing this, I am creating a set of wrapper components that encapsulate more functionality than just the chart itself, e.g. titles, dialogs, measures etc.  In doing this, I am finding that how vue-chartjs adds complexity to my task for multiple reasons, e.g. the structure of renderChart props doesn't match the parameters of chartjs itself.  Also, vue-chartjs has its own unique capabilities that add a layer of complexity to using chartjs.

I assume there are other complexities that are reduced by using vue-chartjs, but... my question is:
Do experienced Vue developers use vue-chartjs to access chart.js?  Or do you go direct to chart.js?  My first pass approach was derived from a tutorial, and I didn't question it at the time.  Now that I'm doing more complex things, vue-chartjs is getting in my way as I try to simplify and minimize data marshaling.

For now I am working around these issues, but if it is reasonable to create my own wrappers rather than add an unnecessary level through vue-charts, I would like to try that.  But I don't want to venture into this without first asking for feedback from other dashboard folks who have done it!

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally speaking, I've found in some code reviews less experienced devs tend to rely on `vue-****` wrapper libraries even when there is little (or even no) benefit. Adding additional libraries increases exposure to more dependencies, each of which theoretically carries a potential for security vulnerability. I've also seen the opposite, where the functionality is re-invented when a vue library is available and would save significant amount of time and have a more robust component(like including aria fields or thoroughly tested with various browsers). The **tl;dr;** being, I take is on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Daniel. I can give another example where I used vue-popper wrapper package. The component itself is not bad, it's well done, however, it uses the previous major version of popper.js which lacks good new features and improvements. For this reason I created later my own implementation of vue popper with the latest version.